# Use named range to trigger Worksheet_Change event causes 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, named-ranges

I have an excel workbook and I am running some code to remove extra spaces from one cell in several sheets. When I enter something in cell "E4", it removes every instance of " " and replaces it with "". This works as anticipated.

I am trying to get this to work for more than one sheet, by using named ranges. In the sheets, I created a named range "ConfigurationInput" with a scope of sheet.

The following code is in one of the sheets, and it functions as expected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
        Call RemoveSpaces(Range("E4"))
    End If

End Sub
```

This calls the following Sub, located in a module:

```
Sub RemoveSpaces(RngRemove)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = RngRemove
    
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(rng, " ", "")

End Sub
```

I am trying to replace "E4" with the named range "ConfigurationInput", and I am receiving the following error which crashes Excel:

[image: error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed]

Does anybody have a suggestion? I tried simplifying to a single cell and using .Address but that didn't work either:

```
If Target.Address = Range("ConfigurationInput").Address Then
```

Comment: `Sub RemoveSpaces(RngRemove as Range)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - it seems like in Excel 365 one can no longer use the same sheet-scoped name on more than one sheet, but each name must be unique. Do you have the same behavior on your end? If so, that's a huge change, which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: I do not have that restriction.  I just named two ranges on different sheets the same name. @BigBen

Comment: @ScottCraner - well it's a good thing I asked. I restarted Excel and now no longer have that issue.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I appreciate your suggestion. I tested `Sub RemoveSpaces(RngRemove as Range)` but it did not work. I had to wrap the IF statement with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ConfigurationInput")) Is Nothing Then
        Call FixConfig(Range("ConfigurationInput"))
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I had to wrap the code with `Application.EnableEvents = False`  and `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: That means you're working with a workbook-scoped range.

Comment: That's the odd thing - it is a worksheet-scoped range, but it is acting like a workbook-scoped range. I did create it first as a workbook-scoped range, and deleted that to re-create the worksheet-scoped range. Perhaps there is some fragment that persisted in the background?

Comment: Perhaps. Note that you should include an error handler so that in case of error, the `Application.EnableEvents = True` still gets executed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am not familiar with error handlers - could you please elaborate on how to implement the error handler?